# node-http2 reuse connection

Tags: node.js, http2

I try to consume an REST API with the [node-http2](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=agent) package.
The API supports HTTP/2.

I GET a file with two related resources:

```
GET /article/223
    GET /comment/123
    GET /comment/322
```

Shouldn't the two `/comment` requests be faster than the `/article` request because of http/2 multiplexed connections?

I already have a custom agent with keep-alive

```
new http2.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
```

Сan i check when a new connection gets opened or how many connections are open at a specific moment of time?

Answer (score 0):

I think keep-alive is not needed:
"Under HTTP/2 keep alives are the default and HTTP/2 doesn't use the connection header" - [HTTP2 and NGINX - when would I use a keepalive directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188404/http2-and-nginx-when-would-i-use-a-keepalive-directive)

Monitoring connections:
"Other than using Wireshark 2.0, one of the easiest ways to actually see the individual binary frames is by using the net-internals tab of Google Chrome (type chrome://net-internals/#http2 into the address bar). The data can be hard to understand for large Web pages. Rebecca Murphey helpfully wrote a useful tool for displaying it visually in the command line."
https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/02/09/http2-best-practices-web-performance/